# Problem with xrdp (xvnc) when are already a session oppened in local

Tags: centos, vnc, xrdp, gdm

**Description of steps:**

- The user came to the office and login in Gnome 3 session.
- The user finishes their workday in the office, but forget to log out.
- Later, the user wants to do "Home Office" and it connects to their workstation via XRDP.

**Expected behavior:**

The user must log in in a new XRDP session.

**Problem:**

The XRDP conectión it doesn't work because there is already an opened session. Keeps in black screen and drop the conection after 1 second.

If I send a reboot command, it works again

**Asking for help:**

- There is a method to have the local sessión and the Xdrp session at the same time?
- Or maybe a shell command that closes the local session when XRDP trying to connect?

**I am Using:**

- Centos 8.
- Xrdp from the EPEL repo and with Xnvc in the config file.

```
# /etc/gdm/custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false
WaylandEnable=false

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
#Enable=true
```

```
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true

port=3389

; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
; use this only with number alone in port above
; prefer use vsock://<cid>:<port> above
use_vsock=false

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true

; set tcp send/recv buffer (for experts)
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate

; minimum security level allowed for client for classic RDP encryption
; use tls_ciphers to configure TLS encryption
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high

; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=

; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=24 # Do not lower to 16, doesn't work
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=65

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true


[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
```